# Text Field Keeps Changing in Selenium Script

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I'm running a Selenium Python script that is running on Google Chrome, and I have encountered an input field that I can currently clear and edit, but when the focus is taken away from the object, the field immediately reverts to whatever today is. Here is my code:

```
fromm = driver.find_element_by_id("summaryCal1")
too = driver.find_element_by_id("summaryCal2")

single_date = start_date
strDate = str(single_date.month) + "/" + str(single_date.day) + "/" + str(single_date.year)

#select all and overwrite the date that is currently in the field. 
#fromm.click() -- this works with click or no click
fromm.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
fromm.send_keys(strDate)
time.sleep(3)

too.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
too.send_keys(strDate)
time.sleep(3)
```

Here is the HTML from the webpage I'm at:

```
<div id="chk_dates_summary">
            <div class="fr_date">
                <label>From</label>
                <div class="input-with-symbol">
                    <input type="text" name="summaryCal1" id="summaryCal1" class="calendarFocus calendar-with-symbol"> <span class="symbol populateOnClick"><img height="17px" width="20px" src="resources-261/images/calendar_icon_small.png"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="to_date">
                <label>To</label>
                <div class="input-with-symbol">
                    <input type="text" name="summaryCal2" id="summaryCal2" class="calendarFocus calendar-with-symbol"> <span class="symbol populateOnClick"><img height="17px" width="20px" src="resources-261/images/calendar_icon_small.png"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Once my strDate is inserted, it instantly switches back to today's date - I had put a time.sleep() between lines of code and I found that my date goes indeed get inserted into the field, but once the next line of code runs, it's gone. Any ideas?

Comment: Some calendar might require to select dates directly from calendar and  sendkeys won't work. If you could share your URL then it helps to investigate more easily

Comment: You are probably right about the calendar/date affecting the sendkeys. The site requires a login and subscription, but here is the address: https://apps.azuga.com/azuga/reports.html?l=en_US#summaryV2